# Very simple jquery ui drag and drop does not drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

WHy doesn't the drag box drop?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#content {
    background:#CCCCCC;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}
#drop {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background:#00FFFF;
    float:right;
}
#drag {
    background:#009966;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
}
.active {
    background:#FFCC33;
}

</style>
<script type="text/ecmascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#drag').draggable({
            containment: '#content',
            scrollSensitivity: 60,
            revert: true,
            cursor: 'move'
        });

        $('#drop').droppable({
            accept: '#drag',
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).addClass('.active');
            }
        });

    });
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>


<body>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="drag">

        </div>
        <div id="drop">

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't drop because i need to change the revert to 'invalid' instead of true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 issues happening.

The javascript include for jQuery should be `javascript` instead of `ecmascript`:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The `.active` class won't override `#drag` (because it's less specific) you need to change the CSS to:

```
#drop.active { background:#FFCC33; }
```

And in jQuery don't use the `.` when using the `addClass()` method, just use the class name:

```
$(this).addClass('active');
```

Here's your source with those changes, this should have the intended effect:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#content {
    background:#CCCCCC;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}
#drop {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background:#00FFFF;
    float:right;
}
#drag {
    background:#009966;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
}
#drop.active { background:#FFCC33; }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#drag').draggable({
            containment: '#content',
            scrollSensitivity: 60,
            revert: true,
            cursor: 'move'
        });

        $('#drop').droppable({
            accept: '#drag',
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        });

    });
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>


<body>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="drag">

        </div>
        <div id="drop">

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Even though this is not what i was getting after, thank you for pointing out these errors. It helped resolve a piece of my issue

Answer (score 0):

`draggable` makes the contents of your selector draggable, not the selector itself. Your divs are blank. Add something in there and those elements will becomes draggable.

PS: You should be a little more verbose in your question. Don't say "Why doesn't it work?". Ask why specific things don't work.

Answer (score 0):

It works. If you are wondering why it doesn't change the color, it's because the styles defined for `#droppable` take priority over `active` so the color wont change. Add a `!important` rule for the background color in `active` and it should work.